# HTML section background video

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'm attempting to implement a background video simiilar to [this](http://pupunzi.com/mb.components/mb.YTPlayer/demo/demo_domElement.html). Stretching the full screen but maintain a height of 400px. How may I achieve this without JavaScript? Heres the HTML I have so far

```
    <div class="project__three">
        <div class="grid">
                <video src="./videos/test.mp4" id="bg-video" muted autoplay loop ></video>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: would `   .bg-video{min-width:100%;}   ` in your CSS not do it ?

Comment: That makes it completely full screen. Im trying to make it 100% width and 400px height. I'm able to make an image like that using background-size, but failing with the video element @Billy

Comment: min-width:100%;max-height:400px;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a blog post about this a while back.  I don't think you're using the video tag correctly.  I think it should look more like this:

```
<video muted autoplay loop>
   <source src="http://yourwebsite.com/your-video-file.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
   <source src="http://yourwebsite.com/your-video-file.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
   <source src="http://yourwebsite.com/your-video-file.webm" type="video/webm"/>
    Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
</video>
```

I'm pretty sure you have to include the "ogg" and "webm" extensions for HTML5 video to fully work.

Here is a [link](http://benkaminski.com/2013/05/26/responsive-html5-css3-video-background-in-div-no-javascript/) to my post where go into full detail.

Answer (score 0):

This works with the above, doesn't look great though.Put it in your css

```
   video{
         webkit - transform:scaleX(2);
        moz - transform:scaleX(2);
         transform:scaleX(2);
  }
```

Comment: thats a great attempt and its supported in most browsers, however the quality is very distorted. I may opt for object-fit/object-position which produce greater quality and produce a fall-back image for non supporting browsers :(

Comment: to do a fall back image with this just add a background url to the bg-video container, the video will cover it in supported browsers.